# Get on/off state of a PC (with 12V or 5V)

Tags: power-supply, motherboard, pc

On a classical ATX mother board, how to get the ON/OFF "state" of the PC with a voltage?

- 0V if the PC is off
- 5V if the PC is on

(or 12V or any other voltage)

I thought about just taking this on a Molex connecter:

[image]

but I am not sure if this will really reflect the ON/OFF state.

Maybe these connectors always give 5V if the power supply is connected, and even if the PC is off?

**Or are there pins that give the ON/OFF state, in the ATX standard, present on all motherboards?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The power rails are typically controlled such that they are off when the PSU is off, and on when it is on, so you could use them directly.

Alternatively, the main 20/24pin ATX connector has a `PWR_OK` ('Power Good') signal (pin 8) which goes high once the power supply is turned on, *and* the various power rails are stable. If you have easy access to that signal, I would go for that instead. Otherwise just use the 5V rail.

Comment: Thanks! How to access the 20/24pin ATX connector `PWR_OK` without removing this connector? More generally, which solution do you think is the best / and reliable to get this on/off state signal? Molex connector?

Comment: Could use a cable splice and/or a short ATX extension cable. 5V rail from a 4-pin molex is probably the easiest way.

Answer (score 2):

Those pins have 5V and 12V only when ATX supply is turned on. You can use them.